# Splitting A String In Java?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

This is in Java 7

I do not know regular expressions, so I was wondering if anybody knew how I could use the split method to get all usernames out of the string:

```
{tchristofferson=10, mchristofferson=50}
```

and then add the usernames to a String[] array? These are just two usernames in there, but I want this to work for an endless amount of usernames.

Usernames require the following format:

3-16 characters, no spaces, A-Z upper and lower case and 0-9, only special character is _ (underscore).

Comment: What are the valid characters in a username?  Can it include numbers and special characters like _- and so on.

Comment: with which version of java you should complete this task?

Comment: I am doing this in java 7

Comment: the usernames have these requirements: 3-16 characters, no spaces, A-Z upper and lower case and 0-9, only special character is _ (underscore).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like JSON, so the "right" answer would probably be to use a JSON parser. If this is not an option, you can remove the enclosing `{}`, split the string according to `", "`, and then split each string according to the `=` sign, taking the first item:

```
String input = "{tchristofferson=10, mchristofferson=50}";
List<String> users =
    Arrays.stream(input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).split(", "))
          .map(s -> s.split("=")[0])
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It's not valid JSON: JSON should have quotes around String  values (and, strictly, key names too). Most parsers would reject this input.

Comment: actually JSON should have colons instead of equals

Comment: [Pattern#splitAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) may have been more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the wrong (job security) way:

```
String[] usernames = str.substring(1)
                        .split("=\\d+[,}]\\s*");
```

---

Why is this the wrong way?  We are throwing out the stuff we don't want.
The first character (whatever it is), and hoping that `"=#, "` and "=#}" is the only stuff we don't want.
If the string began with `"{ tchristofferson=10"`, then the first username would get a leading space.

The better way is to match the stuff you do want.  And now that I'm not trying to create the answer on an iPhone screen, here it is:

```
    String input = "{tchristofferson=10, mchristofferson=50}";

    Pattern USERNAME_VALUE = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = USERNAME_VALUE.matcher(input);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    String[] usernames = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

This assumes each character of your usernames match the `\w` pattern (i.e., `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and other alphanumeric Unicode code points).  Modify if your username requirements are more/less restrictive.

`(\w+)` is used to capture the username as `matcher.group(1)`, which is added to the list which is eventually turned into your `String[]`.

`(\d+)` is also being used to capture the number associated with this user as `matcher.group(2)`.  This capture group is not (presently) being used, so you could remove the parenthesis for a small efficiency gain, i.e., `"(\\w+)=\\d+"`.  I included it in case you wanted to do something with those values as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting whenever there is not (^) a word (A-Za-z):

```
String[] tokens = test.split("[^A-Za-z]");
```

And if don't mind using a List, try it like @Mureinik suggested with:

```
    List<String> tokens2 = Arrays.stream(test.split("[^A-Za-z]"))
            .distinct()
            .filter(w -> !w.isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit1**:

<s>If the list contains numbers try:</s>

<s>String[] tokens = test.split("[^A-Za-z\w]");</s>

I highly recommend this site if you wish to experiment with regex:

http://regexr.com/

Comment: how could I do this if the username may contain numbers?

Comment: `[^A-Za-z\\w]` is equivalent to `[^\\w]`, which is equivalent to `\W`.  This gives an output of `["", "tchristofferson", "10", "", "mchristofferson", "50"]`, where `""`, `"10"`, `""` and `"50"` are not usernames.

Answer (score 0):

If **username** includes **numbers** and special characters like **=** then:

```
String str = "tchristofferson=10,mchristofferson=50";    
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile(",");
String[] usernames = ptn.split(str);
```